# Is aws api gateway supports mutual TLS connection with backend services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-api-gateway

I'm new to AWS API gateway.We are trying to connect backend service which is outside AWS using mutual TLS from API gateway.

Is this possible using AWS API gateway.If so ,can you please let me know how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Mutual authentication is not supported by API Gateway. You can setup authentication for your backend using [client-side certificates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html).

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=297461

Comment: I went to the links provided but no one had commented that mutual authentication is not supported .Can you please let me know where can i get that AWS api gateway is not supporting  mutual authentication in official pages if possible .

Comment: @kakollu did you manage to make it work?